# getView never called

Tags: android, gridview, fragment, custom-adapter

I am implementing a grid view which is inside fragment with a custom adapter. But the getView() of custom adapter has never called. I set the grid view like below.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
ArrayList<ObjectPack> objects;
GridView gridView;
ThumbnailGridViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    objects = new ArrayList<ObjectPack>();
    objects.add(createMockObjectPack());
    gridView = (GridView)getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_story_main, null).findViewById(R.id.gridView_Main);
    adapter = new ThumbnailGridViewAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.item_thumbnail, objects);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_story_main, container, false);

    return view;
}

private ObjectPack createMockObjectPack() {
    ObjectPack mock;
    int id = 1;
    String title = "test";
    String description = "TEST";
    int iconId = R.drawable.title;
    ArrayList<Integer> imoticonIds = null;

    mock = new ObjectPack(id, title, description, iconId, imoticonIds);

    return mock;
}
}
```

And next is the layout xml of the fragment. The text view is shown well but the grid view isn't.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_storyMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/message_storyMain" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView_storyMain_theme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And whenever I tried to debug, the break points in onCreate and onCreateView hit four times, why is it?

Please help me, any advice would be appreciated a lot!!!

================ added ======================

Below is my adapter code, by x90's advice, getView() is called once but screen is all black now. I'm very new to android please help me, Thanks!!!

```
public class ThumbnailGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
int itemLayoutId;
List<ObjectPack> objects;
LayoutInflater inflater;

BitmapLoader loader;

public ThumbnailGridViewAdapter(Context context, int itemLayoutId, List<ObjectPack> objects) {
    super();

    this.context = context;
    this.itemLayoutId = itemLayoutId;
    this.objects= objects;

    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    loader = new BitmapLoader(context.getResources(), R.drawable.loading);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int index) {
    return objects.get(index);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int index) {
    return objects.get(index).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(itemLayoutId, parent, false);
    }
    else {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_item_thumbnail);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        loader.LoadBitmap(objects.get(index).getIconId(), imageView);

        TextView text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item_thumbnail);
        text.setText(objects.get(index).getTitle());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Post your `ThumbnailGridViewAdapter` code.

Comment: @Gunaseelan I did, please take a look at it and any advice will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in onCreateView:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView_storyMain_theme);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And remove GridView creation in onCreate method.
If your adapter is fine - grid will appear.

Comment: Thanks!! It made my code one step foward I guess. But I'm stuck at another problem. getView() called once, but the screen turned to black. I guess something wrong in adapter.